# Google Compute Engine Virtual Machine: Unable to connect via SSH using any method

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine

When using SSH to connect to my VM, the process hangs indefinitely when the VM asks the metadata server for an authentication token. This happens when using a browser shell (the SSH button on the VM tab) and also when using Cloud Shell. This is the output from the serial console, which I am able to connect to.

```
serialport: Connected to peerless-rite-139921.us-central1-b.wrangl-reload port 1 (session ID: 305e0a35ea71dec437aaae0302eb479de1d20562, active connections: 1).
Jul 25 18:38:34 wrangl-reload dhclient[567]: DHCPACK of 10.128.0.3 from 169.254.169.254
Jul 25 18:38:34 wrangl-reload dhclient[567]: bound to 10.128.0.3 -- renewal in 37979 seconds.
Jul 25 18:46:11 wrangl-reload collectd[692]: write_gcm: Asking metadata server for auth token
Jul 25 19:19:47 wrangl-reload systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt download activities...
Jul 25 19:19:54 wrangl-reload systemd[1]: Started Daily apt download activities.
Jul 25 19:19:54 wrangl-reload systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 11h 43min 24.702830s random time.
Jul 25 19:19:54 wrangl-reload systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 2h 56min 56.298278s random time.
Jul 25 19:21:11 wrangl-reload collectd[692]: write_gcm: Asking metadata server for auth token
Jul 25 19:53:11 wrangl-reload collectd[692]: write_gcm: Asking metadata server for auth token
Jul 25 20:51:11 wrangl-reload collectd[692]: write_gcm: Asking metadata server for auth token
```

In addition, if I try to SSH from my Mac using Terminal using a public key I created locally, I get `Permission denied (publickey).`
I have tried accessing the server with SSH from other VMs, which also resulted in `Permission denied (publickey).`

The disk is not full.
I have tried using a `startup-script` in metadata, but that too fails.

The firewall rules are project-wide and we have two other VMs in the same project, which are both reachable with SSH.

Comment: The log line means that the Stackdriver agent is picking logs. Doesn't necessarily seem to be directly related to SSH. What else is there? Something like `GCEGuestAgent` maybe? It provisions SSH users. Also, you tried "*accessing the server from other VMs*", did it work? Same VPC? Firewall rules? Are you using SSH keys in the metadata? If so, have you tried re-adding them? What's your setup SSH-wise?

Comment: @yyyyahir Thanks. I edited the question as much as I could to address your comment. I see no GCEGuestAgent in the console output. I am able to access the other two VMs in the project by clicking the SSH button. The firewall rules are project-wide, and I have reinstalled keys in metadata several times.

Comment: I'm skeptical the messages are related to SSH. [The originator is `collectd` trying to reach the metadata server, a typical operation for Stackdriver](https://github.com/Stackdriver/collectd/issues/139). Could be a transient failure in the metadata server. Have you tried [setting SSH keys manually](https://github.com/Stackdriver/collectd/issues/139#issuecomment-508287374)? What's the full SSH client debug output? If the firewall is correctly set in GCP, is the same at iptables/ufw level? Have you nmap'ed your server ports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple rounds of Google support, they recommended re-installing the Google Guest Environment. They said, "It's very sensitive. If you change permissions on a single file, it can break." After reinstalling, the issue was fixed.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/guest-environment
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/install-guest-environment#in_place